# Code for creating 2d texture from cloud of points

Tags: java, 3d

I'm looking for java library which help me generating textures for models used in 3d engine in javascript. Imagine following workflow:

1. 3d coordinates with additional data
2. 2D texture - image colorized by data plus UV map
3. 3D js engine loads simple mesh with associated texture and UV map

My meshes - buildings defined polygon extruded by building height. It looks promising from performance reason load textures instead of constructing meshes and materials based on data.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I know it is not possible create automatically UV map for whichever prism.